# Centering a div in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following CSS:

```
html, body {
        background-color:black;
        font-family:"arial bold";
        overflow:auto;
        text-align: center; 
    }
div#content {
        width:792px;
        height:100%;
        padding:0px;
    }

div#header  {
        height:216px;
        width:100%;
    }
```

The HTML code I have is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Think in a NEW BOX.
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/title-1.png" /><img src="images/title-2a.png" /><img src="images/title-3.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, this works great in IE.  The div centers perfectly (header).  In Google Chrome, however, the div is left aligned.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this 'problem' too today. Solved it with using `display: inline-block;`. Working browsers won't change and if it's already working, this won't mix up IE old.

Comment: It will mess up not-IE old though.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing:

1. A doctype (so IE is emulating bugs from the IE 4/5 days to cope with awful, ancient webpages)
2. That a div element is a block element so `text-align` does not influence it
3. `auto` left and right margins on the div.

See [Centring using CSS](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/) for a longer explanation with diagrams

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px; /* Your width */
}
```

to center your div. It allows your div to choose a variable margin for left and right, that results in a centered div. This should work for *all* browser.

Answer (score 2):

Even better solution is to center the block like this:

```
#content 
{
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

This method is used by... well, just about everyone (including SO).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a fixed width and use `margin: 0 auto;`.